# Daydream settings

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a settings for my `Daydream` and according to the documentation, I need to create a xml file, like this:

```
 <dream xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:settingsActivity="com.example.app/.MyDreamSettingsActivity" />
```

However, my `Activity` is in a library project (called com.project.base) and I keep getting this error in `Logcat` when clicking on the setting button:

```
 11-16 23:01:29.331: E/AndroidRuntime(28908): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.project.base/com.project.base.SettingsDayDream}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

I have my xml file setup like this:

```
 <dream xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:settingsActivity="com.project.base/.SettingsDayDream" />
```

but I've tried all variation, such as `com.project.base/com.project.base.SettingsDayDream`
and just `com.project.base.SettingsDayDream`, but nothing seems to work.

I've declared the activity in the `AndroidManifest.xml` like this:

```
    <activity android:name="com.project.base.SettingsDayDream" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
```

as well as the service:

```
<service android:name="com.project.base.DayDream" android:exported="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.service.dreams.DreamService" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.service.dream" android:resource="@xml/daydream" />
</service>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your `daydream.xml`. The format for the `android:settingsActivity` is `current.app.package/com.project.base.SettingsActivity`

So `current.app.package`, before the `/`, needs to be your current app, not the library project.